# javascript store data object in temporary variable for access on next page

Tags: javascript

I am pulling in data from an API and showing each item.

I want to be able to 'click' on one of the returned objects and hold parts from that object 'name, author, body' in a temporary variable and then have that data accessible on a different page for display.

How can I do this?

My code to show results looks like this:

```
$("#run-search").on('click', function(event){
  event.preventDefault();

  searchTerm = $("#search-term").val().trim();

  $.get("/api/search/" + searchTerm, function(){
    console.log('request');
  })
  .done(function(data){
    for(var i = 0; i < data.objects.length; i++){
      var newDiv = $("<li>").text(data.objects[i].title);
      var newButton = $("<button>").text(data.objects[i].title + " " + data.objects[i].authors[0].name);

      $("#results").append(newDiv);
      $("#results").append(newButton);
```

Comment: If you want to store the data for the next page, store it in localStorage and then retrieve it from localStorage when you are on the next page. (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)

Comment: The usual way is to pass the stored data to your web server in a HTTP request (querystring or form body).

Answer (score 2):

You can make use of the `localStorage` to store and retrieve items in browser.
The localStorage has no expiration time. You can find more information [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/LocalStorage)

**How to Store in local Storage?**

`localStorage.setItem('name', 'Byron');`

**How to Retrieve item from local Storage?**

`var nameValue = localStorage.getItem("name")`

Comment: `localStorage` is not necessarily cleared when the browser is closed - that depends on settings.

Comment: Updated the answer to make it more concrete about the expiration. Though, different browser have a little bit different behavior on clearing the local storage. Thanks for your note.